# how to center the content of right div in center also when @media screen and (max-width : 360px) it should be at center

Tags: html, css

> how to center the div content in float right div when it is text-align:left

```
<html><head></head><body>
    <div class="top">top</div>
    <div class="fleft"></div>
    <div class="fright">
    <h1>this is heading</h1>
    <p>* test 1test 1test 1 </p>
    <p>* test 1test 1test 1 </p>
    <p>* test 1test 1test 1 </p>
    <p>* test 1test 1test 1 </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/jimoscarlobo/7f9r7aom/)

Comment: Why can't you just align the text center?

Comment: To center text in a div, you add `text-align:center;` If you want the text to be left aligned, but still be centered, you wrap the elements in a container div (within the other div) and set `margin-left:auto;` `margin-right:auto;` and a width. Another option is to add `position:absolute;` and a `left:` and/or `right:` property. (If you use absolute, you add `position:relative;` to the parent element and you can drop the margin-left and margin-right properties and you don't need to add a width)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add **text-align:center** to your Media Query

```
   @media screen and (max-width : 360px) {

      .top{width: 100%;}

      .fleft{width: 100%;}

      .fright {
          width:100%;
          text-align:center;
      }
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wilsoda/4yv8emm1/

And if you want the content wrapping centered but the text aligning left just add and **Inner** div with whatever width you want.

```
@media screen and (max-width : 360px) {
.top {
    width: 100%;
}
.fleft {
    width: 100%;
}
.fright {
    width:100%;
}
.inner {
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wilsoda/5g2ccd4p/

Hope This Helps!